# Multiple htaccess rewrite rules

Tags: .htaccess

I'm using the below htaccess file.First one is working fine.But the second one is not working.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Epropertiesnew/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /Properties(?:\.php)?\?project=([^&]+)&property=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /ViewNewProjects(?:\.php)?\?newproject=([^&]+)&url=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# PHP hiding rule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^([A-Z,0-9-]+)/([A-Z,0-9-]+)/?$ Properties.php?project=$1&property=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([A-Z,0-9-]+)/([A-Z,0-9-]+)/?$ ViewNewProjects.php?newproject=$1&url=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

If I commented the first one,second one is working fine.Please help me to fix this.

Comment: The matching patterns for the two rewrite rules at the end (assuming those are the ones you mean) are exactly the same, so you're never going to hit the second one. How are you expecting it to work?

Comment: First one will load like this -> http://exploreproperties.in/Prestige-Kensington-Gardens-Apartment/2bhk-Flat-For-Rent-85479670 , Second one also will look exactly the same but it will call the different url

Comment: If it's going to look exactly the same, how do you expect Apache to know which url to call?

Comment: First one will call this url - Properties.php.Second one will call this url - ViewNewProjects.php.But for these two url i will pass two parameters.